# ¿cómo validar en laravel, peso en tamaño y dimenciones de imagenes?

Tags: php, laravel, validación

Tengo el siguiente problema de validación de imágenes.
Necesito validar el peso en tamaño y dimensiones de la imagen que voy a cargar.
Estoy realizando esta validaciones con validator.
Espero puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor revisa [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), reformula tu pregunta, para que sea más fácil poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 2):

Para realizar lo que quieres sería algo así:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'avatar' => 'dimensions:min_width=100,min_height=200|max:5000',
        ]);
```

Donde a `dimensions` le estás especificando que la altura mínima sea de 200 y el ancho mínimo de 100, la regla `max` especifica que debe de ser igual o menor a lo especificado, para archivos le tienes que enviar el peso en kilobytes, en el ejemplo que te puse le estás diciendo que el máximo peso del archivo no debe de pasar de los 5 megabytes.

Para más información, checa la [documentación oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#available-validation-rules)